# Autofill between 2 values in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, autocomplete, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have 2 values(Min and Max) and 8 empty cells between them in column H

[image]

I would like to auto-fill the empty cells.
It is possible to do it in excel like this https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2892-excel-list-all-numbers-between-two-numbers.html#a1

Any idea whats the equivalent option in google sheets? Also if there is a way to do it both linear/non-linear way?

Answer (score 2):

- go to **File**
- select **Spreadsheet settings**
- choose **Calculation**
- and turn on **Iterative calculation**
- then use this formula:

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("B"&
 MAX(IF(B3:B<>"", ROW(B3:B), )))+SORT(ROW(INDIRECT("B1:B"&
 MAX(IF(B3:B<>"", ROW(B3:B), ))-2)), 1, 0)*(B1-INDIRECT("B"&
 MAX(IF(B3:B<>"", ROW(B3:B), ))))/(
 MAX(IF(B3:B<>"", ROW(B3:B), ))-1))
```

[image: 0]

where B1 is the minimum value and last value in column is maximum (or reversed)

[image: 0]

Comment: #between numbers